# How can you use await to hold the scope of a using clause?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have actions that return void. but I need the call to keep the current scope open while it runs.

```
    public class CancellationHelper
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public void Run(Action<CancellationToken> action)
    {
        if (_cts != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            action(_cts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

if the action is `async`, the `_cts` will be disposed before the method completes. the return type is void, so I can't just await it... I've read you are supposed to avoid `Task.Run` and favor async/await, but I don't see how to do this for using clauses.

Is `await Task.Run(action);` dirty? is this spinning up another 'task' or thread to wait for something that spins up a task or thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `action` is an `async void` method.
**Don't do that**.
It is impossible to find out when an `async void` method finishes.

Instead, you need to make your method accept a `Func<Task>`.
You can then write `await action();`.

Comment: excellent, that's what I wanted to know, I can now go find all the places I called `Task.Run(()=>action()).Await();` and know what's going wrong

Comment: yes, they are `async void` methods. I imagine then, that `async void` with side effects is always a bad idea.

Comment: @Maslow: `async void` is _always_ a bad idea, whether there are side-effects or not.  The only place you should ever use `async void` is in UI event handlers.

Comment: I thought the compiler automatically makes the return type for asynchronous void functions to `Task`.

Comment: @JeffMercado: No.  `async` functions need explicitly-declared return types just like other functions.  However, `async` functions are not allowed to return anything but `void` or `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Comment: That's what I said. Though in this case here it doesn't apply. I didn't realize he has a delegate, he's not defining a `async` function.